# Appending ints to char* and then clearing

Tags: c++, char, serial-port, int, arduino

I'm working on a project using an Arduino and as such, I'm reading from a serial port (which sends `int`s). I need to then write this serial communication to an LCD, which takes a `char*`.

I need to read several characters from the serial port (two integers) into a string. After both have been received, I then need to clear the string to prepare for the next two characters.

[TLDR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLDR): How do I append an `int` to a `char*`, and then clear the string after it has two characters?

Comment: This kind of stuff is simpler if you just use a stl string.  There is a c_str() method which hands you the char* you need.  Though using sprintf and such has less overhead, which might matter.

Comment: The Arduino has limited memory to work with and all of their examples use char*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A char is a single character, whereas a char* can be a pointer to a character or a pointer to the first character in a C string, which is an array of chars terminated by a null character.

You can't use a char to represent an integer longer than 1 digit, so I'm going to assume you did in fact mean char*.

If you have

```
char buffer[10];
```

then you can set `buffer` to a string representing an int `n` with sprintf

```
sprintf(buffer, "%d", n);
```

And when you're done with it, you can clear the string with

```
sprintf(buffer, "");
```

Hope that's what you were asking for, and good luck!

Comment: It seems to work, but using `buffer = "";` gives me a compile error: "incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [1]' to 'char [10]'"

Comment: Hm. Sorry my C is a little rusty. Go with sprintf(buffer, "");

Comment: OK, that works, but buffer appears to be set to "49" (the ASCII code for 1). Any ideas?

Comment: No, this is before that. (Reworded my question too, it should be better now.)

Comment: I can just use chr(19) on the computer (sending) end, which lets this code work, so accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't read into a char *, it is  a pointer. You can read into the memory pointed to by the pointer, provided it points to something valid. As for clearing, it's not obvious what you mean by that.

Bottom line is that you need to post some actual code that attempts to do what you want, and ask about that.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise the difference between a char and a char*. I've changed my question to say char. Also, by clearing, I mean making the char completely blank (no values).

Comment: No, you don't mean a char either - a char is a  single byte. Please post some code!